# Tortoise SVN Explorer integration broken since 1.6.10?

Tags: tortoise-svn

I run Tortoise SVN on a number of machines, all Windows 7 x64.

Ever since 1.6.10 was released, the context menu in Windows Explorer has been missing.  I've tried every release since then, and keep going back to 1.6.9.  This is the same across all my Win 7 x64 boxes.

Yes, I've downloaded the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Known incompatability with the 1.6.9 installer and all later versions. You need to uninstall and then reinstall cleanly. (Or do a "Repair Install" after installation, which is the same thing as an un/reinstall) [Reference](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/405)